# How do I get my redirects to work with netlify?

Tags: redirect, github, netlify, url-shortener

I have watched the video from netlify on how to hand;e redirects to make custom domains for pages.  I created the plain text file and entered the format they ask for but when I push the changes to github, the rest of the web pages 404 and cant be found.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.  How can I get redirects to work properly with netlify?

here's the github:
https://github.com/OakHarbor/BobTheDentGuy

and the website:
https://www.bobthedentguy.com/

Here's what I have and what I want it to do.

```
/html/index.html                /
/html/about.html                /about-bob-the-dent-guy
/html/portfolio.html            /portfolio
/html/contact.html              /contact-bob-the-dent-guy
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

You switched the columns. It should be like this:

```
/                           /html/index.html
/about-bob-the-dent-guy     /html/about.html
/portfolio                  /html/portfolio.html
/contact-bob-the-dent-guy   /html/contact.html
```

Comment: thank you!  I rearranged them but nothing changed.  I have the _redirects in my root folder saved as plain text, what else am I missing?

Comment: @ryanp It shouldn't be a text file. The file should be called "_redirects" without any extension.

Comment: it doesn't appear to have a file extension. does it? I still have not figured this problem out